# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (anonymous function) in Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I get uncaught referenceerror: invalid left-hand side in assignment (anonymous function) in google chrome developer tools.  This is the code

```
<!--
_CF_checkreset-password-form = function(_CF_this)
{
    //reset on submit
    _CF_error_exists = false;
    _CF_error_messages = new Array();
    _CF_error_fields = new Object();
    _CF_FirstErrorField = null;


    //display error messages and return success
    if( _CF_error_exists )
    {
        if( _CF_error_messages.length > 0 )
        {
            // show alert() message
            _CF_onErrorAlert(_CF_error_messages);
            // set focus to first form error, if the field supports js focus().
            if( _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].type == "text" )
            { _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].focus(); }

        }
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
//-->
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the error is in the first line: `_CF_checkreset-password-form = function(_CF_this)`. You can't create a var with characters like `+` or `-` or any other operator. Try this: `_CF_checkreset_password_form = function(_CF_this)`